Distinct count of entries from logs (Grafana/GraphQL question)
I have a log in the format below:
2024-07-29 21:09:23.937 txn ID: f4501b48-bc73-4ab7-bc10-0f39fc921f49 
2024-07-29 21:08:23.503 txn ID: 06075982-e30d-428c-adb3-4893863fea9e 
2024-07-29 21:07:46.487 txn ID: e134fc86-780b-438a-8ac0-94c0ec8ed0d0 
2024-07-29 21:10:46.487 txn ID: f4501b48-bc73-4ab7-bc10-0f39fc921f49

I need help with a GraphQL query that returns the unique count of the above IDs.
In this case it should be 3.
I've googled and tried a bunch of things but I can't even come close.
This is the query that returns all the entries (not deduped)
{namespace="x", job="y"} |= `txn ID: `

I've tried the below but it doesn't get me the right count
count(count_over_time({namespace="x", job="y"} |= `txn ID:` [$__range] ))

Would appreciate any assistance here.
